# <K extends keyof Obj> appears to be a string inside of the object

Tags: typescript

Here is the simple code illustrating this issue:

```
interface Obj {
    key_a: string;
}

function set<K extends keyof Obj>(key: K, value: Obj[K]) {
    // Error: Property 'key_a' is missing in type '{ [x: string]: Obj[K]; }'
    const obj: Obj = { [key]: value }
    return obj
}
```

Why does `K extends keyof Obj` become a `string`? There is defined constrain in the Generic, and there is no change I can pass something except `'key_a'` to the function.

And to then, if I define another constant which is `keyof Obj` - everything is fine:

```
const k1: keyof Obj = 'key_a'
let obj: Obj = { [k1]: value } // OK

const k2: 'key_a' = 'key_a'
obj = { [k2]: value } // OK
```

So, it leads to the fact that `K extends keyof Obj`, `K !== keyof Obj && K !== 'key_a'`?! But why?

Actually, there is a way to make it more weird:

```
function set<K extends keyof Obj>(key: K, value: Obj[K]) {
    const _key: keyof Obj = key
    const obj: Obj = { [_key]: value } // OK
    return obj
}
```

Comment: It's a bug/limitation/missing feature in TS, as described in [ms/TS#13948](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948). Computed property keys get widened to `string` unless they are of specific string literal types.  In your case, the generic `K` is being widened.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yeah, I suspected it was another TS oddity; I didn't find the related issue. Thank you very much! It indeed covers the question; you can make a complete answer. It would be very nice if you give more details about widening in the context of this example.